# Is it possible to prevent another $digest after $evalAsync ?

Tags: angularjs

example scenario,

*pseudo-code*

```
scope.set_value ( user_input ) { 

    scope.value = user_input;

    // trigger digest : evaluation of several validators

    // execute after digest and prior to DOM rendering
    scope.$evalAsync(function() {

        // check if the value is valid based on 
        // validators calculated during the last digest

        if ( !scope.is_valid() )
            // trigger another digest with null value
            scope.value = null;

        else
            // NO CHANGE
            // prevent another digest... is it possible ? 

    });
```

Leaving aside the possible endless loop that might occur here - Is it possible to cancel the next `$digest` within `$evalAsync` ?

Answer (score 0):

for future reference i'll answer my own question .... it can be achieved with `$$postDigest`

```
scope.set_value ( user_input ) { 

    scope.value = user_input;

    // trigger digest : evaluation of several validators

    // execute after digest and prior to DOM rendering
    scope.$$postDigest(function() {

        // check if the value is valid based on 
        // validators calculated during the last digest

        if ( !scope.is_valid() )
            // trigger another digest with null value
            scope.$apply( function () {  scope.value = null; });

        // NO CHANGE
    });
```